# Visual Studio 2013 Windows 8.1 App Debugging Black Bar Top Right

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I've been unable to figure out what the meaning of this black bar in the top right hand corner is while debugging my Win8 store app. Anyone have an idea how to remove it?

Note I was unable to take a screen snip of it so I had to use my phone.. weird.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look in app.xaml.cs. The code to enable/disable is in the main function there.
DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter

The numbers are performance indicators.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.debugsettings.enableframeratecounter.aspx

Left to right
Left side: App FPS and then App CPU
Right side: Sys FPS and then Sys CPU

Pete